# How can I convert a dictionary into a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a dictionary like:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

How can I convert it to this?

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

And how can I convert it to this?

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Comment: `[tuple(reversed(x)) for x in d.items()]`

Comment: @garej: Given `x` is already a `tuple` in your code (it's the nature of `items` to produce an iterable of `tuple`s), it would be simpler/faster to just do `[x[::-1] for x in d.items()]`; the reversing slice directly constructs a reversed `tuple` of the proper size rather than having the `tuple` constructor iteratively populate (with overallocation and resizing at the end) a `tuple` from a `reversed` iterator.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, you are right. I just wanted to be explicit that it is not always a need for `k, v` pattern in such cases.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

```py
>>> d = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
>>> list(d.items())
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

[For Python 3.6 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/353337), the order of the list is what you would expect.

In Python 2, you don't need `list`.

Answer (score 67):

since no one else did, I'll add py3k versions:

```
>>> d = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
>>> list(d.items())
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
>>> [(v, k) for k, v in d.items()]
[(1, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (2, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use list comprehensions.

```
[(k,v) for k,v in a.iteritems()]
```

will get you `[ ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3) ]` and

```
[(v,k) for k,v in a.iteritems()]
```

the other example.

[Read more about list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) if you like, it's very interesting what you can do with them.

Answer (score 10):

**Create a list of namedtuples**

It can often be very handy to use **[namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)**. For example, you have a dictionary of 'name' as keys and 'score' as values like:

```
d = {'John':5, 'Alex':10, 'Richard': 7}
```

You can list the items as tuples, sorted if you like, and get the name and score of, let's say the player with the highest score (index=0) very Pythonically like this:

```
>>> player = best[0]

>>> player.name
        'Alex'
>>> player.score
         10
```

How to do this:

**list in random order or keeping order of [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):**

```
import collections
Player = collections.namedtuple('Player', 'name score')
players = list(Player(*item) for item in d.items())
```

**in order, sorted by value ('score'):**

```
import collections
Player = collections.namedtuple('Player', 'score name')
```

sorted with lowest score first:

```
worst = sorted(Player(v,k) for (k,v) in d.items())
```

sorted with highest score first:

```
best = sorted([Player(v,k) for (k,v) in d.items()], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[(k,v) for (k,v) in d.iteritems()]
```

and

```
[(v,k) for (k,v) in d.iteritems()]
```

Comment: "[(k,v) for (k,v) in d.iteritems()]" is a terrible equivalent to d.items()

Answer (score 7):

What you want is `dict`'s `items()` and `iteritems()` methods. `items` returns a list of (key,value) tuples. Since tuples are immutable, they can't be reversed. Thus, you have to iterate the items and create new tuples to get the reversed (value,key) tuples. For iteration, `iteritems` is preferable since it uses a generator to produce the (key,value) tuples rather than having to keep the entire list in memory.

```
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Jan 13 2009, 10:26:13) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
>>> a.items()
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
>>> [(v,k) for (k,v) in a.iteritems()]
[(1, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (2, 'b')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

These are the breaking changes from Python 3.x and Python 2.x

For Python3.x use

```
dictlist = []
for key, value in dict.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictlist.append(temp)
```

For Python 2.7 use

```
dictlist = []
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictlist.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a={ 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }

>>> [(x,a[x]) for x in a.keys() ]
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]

>>> [(a[x],x) for x in a.keys() ]
[(1, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (2, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 4):

By `keys()` and `values()` methods of dictionary and `zip`.

`zip` will return a list of tuples which acts like an ordered dictionary.

**Demo:**

```
>>> d = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
>>> zip(d.keys(), d.values())
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
>>> zip(d.values(), d.keys())
[(1, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (2, 'b')]
```

Comment: This worked for me as an alternative to `collections.OrderedDict()` that works better with multiple versions of Python HTTP Requests lib. Even though I dislike the `zip` function name as being somewhat vague/overloaded.

Comment: Note the `zip`-ification is not a "deep" casting, i.e. if there are nested children, they wont be affected. You might have to roll your own recursion.

Answer (score 4):

A alternative one would be

```
list(dictionary.items())  # list of (key, value) tuples
list(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))  # list of (value, key) tuples
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {'John':5, 'Alex':10, 'Richard': 7}
list = []
for i in d:
   k = (i,d[i])
   list.append(k)

print list
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 `dict.values()` not return a list. This is the example

```
mydict = {
  "a": {"a1": 1, "a2": 2},
  "b": {"b1": 11, "b2": 22}
}

print(mydict.values())
> output: dict_values([{'a1': 1, 'a2': 2}, {'b1': 11, 'b2': 22}])

print(type(mydict.values()))
> output: <class 'dict_values'>

print(list(mydict.values()))
> output: [{'a1': 1, 'a2': 2}, {'b1': 11, 'b2': 22}]

print(type(list(mydict.values())))
> output: <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd':3}   
sorted(map(lambda x : (x[1],x[0]),x.items()),key=lambda x : x[0])
```

Lets break the above code into steps

```
step1 = map(lambda x : (x[1],x[0]),x.items())
```

> **x[1] : Value**
> **x[0] : Key**

Step1 will create a list of tuples containing pairs in the form of (value,key) e.g. (4,'c')

```
step2 = sorted(step1,key=lambda x : x[0])
```

Step2 take the input of from Step 1 and sort using the 1st value of the tuple