# Ruby: return a copy of array with [key, value] array from hash

Tags: ruby

In Python there is dict.inspect() method that returns a list of tuples ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674519/how-can-i-convert-a-python-dictionary-to-a-list-of-tuples)).
Is there a similar method in ruby to achieve, well, an array of arrays?

```
#input
{:a => 1, :b => 2}

#result
[[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `to_a` on the hash will do that.

```
{:a => 1, :b => 2}.to_a
#=> [[:b, 2], [:a, 1]]
```

As you can see in the example output, the order is not necessarily preserved (at least not in ruby 1.8, in ruby 1.9 the order is preserved).

Comment: There's `OrderedHash` to preserve order.

Comment: There's also `sort`, which may change the order, but give a consistent output.