# Re-Ordering all nested dictionary elements back to ascending numerical order after deleting an element

Tags: python, list, dictionary, del

I am aware that this is copy of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851093/shifting-dictionary-elements) however, there was no answer that I could see. The asker's problem could be fixed by lists. But I do not believe that mine can. I am using nested lists for an amateur game I'm making, does anyone know how re-order the element back to ascending numerical order after I delete an element.

```
potions = {
            1: {"name": "Potion of Bruh", "amount": 5},
            2: {"name": "Potion of Epic", "amount": 10},
            3: {"name": "Potion of Boi", "amount": 15},
            4: {"name": "Potion of Matt", "amount": 12},
            5: {"name": "Potion of Garfield", "amount": 3}
          }

for i in range(1, len(potions) + 1):
    if "Potion of Boi" == potions[i]["name"]:
        del potions[i]
print(potions)
```

Comment: Before 3.7 dictionaries aren't ordered, so you cannot restore order. After 3.7, dictionary are insertion ordered, so deletions do not affect ordering.

Comment: I tried using python 3.7, same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a dictionary keyed by integers and should be using a list instead. You'll need to change how you remove elements but then the reordering will work properly:

```py
potions = [
            {"name": "Potion of Bruh", "amount": 5},
            {"name": "Potion of Epic", "amount": 10},
            {"name": "Potion of Boi", "amount": 15},
            {"name": "Potion of Matt", "amount": 12},
            {"name": "Potion of Garfield", "amount": 3}
          ]
idx_to_remove = None
for idx, potion in enumerate(potions):
    if "Potion of Boi" == potion["name"]:
        idx_to_remove = idx
        break

if idx_to_remove is not None:
    potions.pop(idx_to_remove)

print(potions)
```

Comment: Awesome, let me give that a try

Comment: Works, great. Also makes adding on items easier

Answer (score 0):

use sorted function

```
potions = {
        9: {"name": "Potion of Bruh", "amount": 5},
        1: {"name": "Potion of Bruh", "amount": 5},
        2: {"name": "Potion of Epic", "amount": 10},
        3: {"name": "Potion of Boi", "amount": 15},
        4: {"name": "Potion of Matt", "amount": 12},
        5: {"name": "Potion of Garfield", "amount": 3}
      }

potions.popitem()
sorted_d = dict(sorted(potions.items(),reverse=False))
print('Dictionary in ascending order by value : ',sorted_d)
```