# Convert a dictionary to a list - Python

Tags: python

I have an output in the following format:

```
report = {frozenset({'banana', 'carrot'}): 3,
          frozenset({'apple'}): 3,
          frozenset({'carrot'}): 4,
          frozenset({'apple', 'carrot'}): 2,
          frozenset({'banana'}): 4}
```

I would like to convert it to the following format:

```
banana carrot, 3
apple, 3
carrot, 4
apple carrot, 2
banana, 4
```

I have tried:

```
for i in report:
   print i
```

Which returns:

```
frozenset(['carrot', 'banana'])
frozenset(['apple'])
frozenset(['carrot', 'apple'])
frozenset(['carrot'])
frozenset(['banana'])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a Python dictionary to a list of tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674519/how-can-i-convert-a-python-dictionary-to-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: I don't think my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674519/how-can-i-convert-a-python-dictionary-to-a-list-of-tuples

Comment: In Python 2, use `.iteritems()` to get the key, value pairs of your dict, then use `' '.join()` on the frozenset keys. Eg, `for s, v in report.iteritems(): print ' '.join(s) + ',', v`. Note that neither dicts nor sets preserve order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer that's similar to Dave's, except it has one less loop (using the join function to simplify things):

```
report = {frozenset({'banana', 'carrot'}): 3,
          frozenset({'apple'}): 3,
          frozenset({'carrot'}): 4,
          frozenset({'apple', 'carrot'}): 2,
          frozenset({'banana'}): 4}

for x in report:
    s=", ".join(x)
    s+=", "+str(report[x])
    print(s)
```

Here is the output:

```
carrot, apple, 2
banana, 4
apple, 3
carrot, 4
carrot, banana, 3
```

If you want to change it to a Python list, you could do this:

```
l=[]
for x in report:
    s=", ".join(x)
    s+=", "+str(report[x])
    l.append(s)
```

And if you want it sorted, try this:

```
l.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did:

```
report = {frozenset({'banana', 'carrot'}): 3,
          frozenset({'apple'}): 3,
          frozenset({'carrot'}): 4,
          frozenset({'apple', 'carrot'}): 2,
          frozenset({'banana'}): 4}

for fruits in report:
    for fruit in fruits:
        print fruit,
    print ' , ',
    print report[fruits]
```

And the output:

> carrot apple  ,  2
>
> apple  ,  3
>
> carrot banana  ,  3
>
> carrot  ,  4
>
> banana ,  4

I had to extract each value from the list within the keys list inside report.

*The print with the comma helps me print without newlines.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```
for f, i in report.items():
    print( ' '.join(f) + ', ' +  str(i) )
```

The method `join` of a string `s` takes an iterable (which `frozenset` is), turns each element into string and joins them with `s` inbetween.
The `dict` objects have the method `items` which returns a list of tuples, which are pairs of keys and values (key is in the `0` position on the tuple, value is in the `1`). Look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674519/how-can-i-convert-a-python-dictionary-to-a-list-of-tuples?lq=1) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the sets to list just by simply using `list(set)`

```
for i in report:
    lst = list(i)
    for n in range(0,len(lst)):
        print(lst[n], end=" ")
    print(report[i])
```