# Creating tuple pairs from a dictionary that has a list as value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying  to get a list of tuple pairs from a dictionary that has a list as value.

```
d={ 'a': [1,2], 'b': [4,5], 'c': [7,8] }
print(d.items())
>>[('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [4, 5]),('c', [7, 8]) ]
```

how do I get the list in this form

```
[('a', 1),('a', 2), ('b',4),('b',5),('c',7),('c',8)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a Python dictionary to a list of tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674519/how-can-i-convert-a-python-dictionary-to-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: This is a little different than that. This is not just turning key:value into a list of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple list comprehension:

```
d = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]}
l = [(k, v) for k in d for v in d[k]]
print(l)  # => [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 4), ('b', 5), ('b', 6)]
```

There's likely other ways to do it, but this is simplistic and doesn't require other libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Its Simple, use one-liner :)

```
>>>
>>> d={ 'a': [1,2], 'b': [4,5], 'c': [7,8] }
>>> [(key,item) for item in value for  key, value in d.iteritems()]
[('a', 4), ('c', 4), ('b', 4), ('a', 5), ('c', 5), ('b', 5)]
>>>
```

if you want to sort use built in funciton

```
>>> d={ 'a': [1,2], 'b': [4,5], 'c': [7,8] }
>>> sorted([(key,item) for item in value for  key, value in d.iteritems()])
[('a', 4), ('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 4), ('c', 5)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [4, 5], 'c': [7, 8]}
```

You can access the key, value pairs using [**`dict.items()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

```
>>> list(d.items())
[('a', [1, 2]), ('c', [7, 8]), ('b', [4, 5])]
```

Then you can iterate over the pairs and iterate over the list values:

```
>>> [(key, value) for (key, values) in d.items()
...  for value in values]
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 7), ('c', 8), ('b', 4), ('b', 5)]
```

The dictionary keys are not ordered alphabetically. If you want the exact output in your question you need to sort them, either before creating your list or after:

```
>>> pairs = _
>>> sorted(pairs)
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('b', 5), ('c', 7), ('c', 8)]
```