# Turn dictionary values into an array python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I named it dict1, for example, but in fact I use a dictionary from the Internet, which I can't rewrite initially.The values are set.

```
dict1 = {'cats':{'1','2'},
        'dogs':{'1'}}
```

Output:

```
{'cats': {'1', '2'}, 'dogs': {'1'}}
```

I want the values to be an array, not a dictionary. Output i want:

```
{'cats': ['1', '2'], 'dogs': ['1']}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a dictionary into a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674519/how-can-i-convert-a-dictionary-into-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: The values are _sets_, not dictionaries. It's unclear how you're making the dictionary, but it you want lists why _are_ they sets to start with?

Comment: I created  example, in reality I use a dictionary that I can't set initially

Comment: @SashSinha that's a possibility - my point is that without some context from the OP we can't know that. What does "from the internet" mean, for example (sets aren't part of JSON)?

Comment: Yes, I actually use a dictionary to delete stop words that are not in the library. So I downloaded a file from github that has this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
dict2 = {k: list(v) for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a `for` loop to parse the dictionary and convert each value to a Python `list` (which is presumably what you mean, when you use the term `array`).

```
dict1 = {'cats':{'1','2'},
        'dogs':{'1'}}

for key, value in dict1.items():
    dict1[key] = list(value)
dict1
```

Yields:

```
{'cats': ['1', '2'], 'dogs': ['1']}
```

As has indicated by @neb, you can "simplify" this by creating a dictionary comprehension (which makes the code a one-liner and potentially produces the end result faster due to under the hood optimizations, but may be less readable/intuitive for folks new to Python).

```
dict1 = {key: list(value) for key, value in dict1.items()}
```

Also yields:

```
{'cats': ['1', '2'], 'dogs': ['1']}
```

### Difference between `sets` and `dictionaries`:

As noted in the comments, several folks have indicated that this

```
{'1', '2'}
```

is NOT a `dictionary`, it is a Python `set`. When printed to the screen, a `set` may superficially look like a `dict`, because of the brackets (which are used for `sets` and `dicts`), but we can see that the data object lacks the key differentiator: the colon to separate a key from a value as shown here in these example `dicts`.:

```
{'1': '2'}
{'key': 'value', 'key1': 'value2'}
```